# Is it wrong to assume that Github will retain the data in the database from Android Studio?

Tags: android, github

I'm new to Android Studio.

I created an Android application where the user needs to login with the user's email and password that's already in the database.

I have never use an API, just a database.

I have uploaded it in Github and I assume that the user can log in based on the email address and password I have provided (which is already stored in the database)

I'm wondering if it's wrong to assume that? Do I need to make a registration fragment as it won't store the data in the database when the user download my source code from Github?

Comment: 1. Your user details are pre populated in a local database? This is a terrible idea. 
2. Your database is uploaded to github?
3. Are you referring to adding new users?

Your question really doesnt make sense. If you use a local db, and store it on github with the source code, when a user tries to log in, they will need to log in with the db creds. since the db creds are already hardcoded, you are pretty much making them irrelevant, as any user could just open the db and grab the proper creds.

Comment: firstly, android studio is an IDE, it just helps you to code your apps, but you're making them with either java or kotlin and a whole bunch of other sdks, so unless you're asking about a feature of the IDE specifically, please don't use the tag :)

Comment: next, Github (which makes use of git) will track and store everything you tell it to. if your app is setup to include a db inside it (already populated) then github will have that file too. don't confuse this with _running_ your app and then creating a db, as that is a file which resides on the device itself, not within your development code

Comment: @la_local_nobody Thank you! I'm pretty new to this so I'll take this as a learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

See comment for more info, but essentially,

If you use a local db, and store it on github with the source code, when a user tries to log in, they will need to log in with the db creds. since the db creds are already hardcoded, you are pretty much making them irrelevant, as any user could just open the db and grab the proper creds, which means you may as well just remove the auth entirely.

Comment: if credentials are hardcoded, a db would be complete overkill, as you could just do something along the lines of `if username is foo and password is bar`

Comment: Agreed, the question itself is not well thought out, but figured I would provide some info anyways.